# How do I check if Mininet is successfully installed on my computer?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, mininet

I have already installed Mininet on my computer, but I need to find out if Mininet has been installed successfully. Is there a command that I should write to make that check or reinstall it native?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run `sudo mn` to run an emulation.

Example:

```
$ sudo mn --version
2.2.1

$ sudo mn
[sudo] password for user: 
*** No default OpenFlow controller found for default switch!
*** Falling back to OVS Bridge
*** Creating network
*** Adding controller
*** Adding hosts:
h1 h2 
*** Adding switches:
s1 
*** Adding links:
(h1, s1) (h2, s1) 
*** Configuring hosts
h1 h2 
*** Starting controller

*** Starting 1 switches
s1 ...
*** Starting CLI:
mininet> 
*** Stopping 0 controllers

*** Stopping 2 links
..
*** Stopping 1 switches
s1 
*** Stopping 2 hosts
h1 h2 
*** Done
completed in 2.173 seconds
```

Alternative, try: `which mn`

```
$ which mn
/usr/bin/mn
```